# Constraints were ignored when trying to implement constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

I'm trying to center a `logoImage` horizontally & vertically by setting constraints but when tested, It was displayed on `(x:0, y:0)`. 
Any idea how to fix this? 
Thanks

```
var movieView : UIView?
let logoImage = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "my_logo"))

// This function runs in viewWillAppear
internal func setupIntroMovie() {
    movieView = UIView(frame: view.frame)
    view.addSubview(movieView!)
    view.addSubview(logoImage)

    let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: logoImage,
                                                  attribute: .centerX,
                                                  relatedBy: .equal,
                                                  toItem: view,
                                                  attribute: .centerX,
                                                  multiplier: 1,
                                                  constant: 0)
    let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: logoImage,
                                                attribute: .centerY,
                                                relatedBy: .equal,
                                                toItem: view,
                                                attribute: .centerY,
                                                multiplier: 1,
                                                constant: 0)
    view.addConstraints([horizontalConstraint,
                              verticalConstraint])
    updateViewConstraints()
}
```

Comment: The term "Error" is too vague. On which line and what is the full error?

Comment: What 'doesn't work'?  does it not appear on the screen as you expect? does the app crash? are there warnings in the logs?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder sorry I forgot to fix title. It doesn't giving me any error

Comment: @Slowpoke Then what is the problem? Do they appear on the screen in an unexpected way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `logoImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` as it determines whether the view’s autoresizing mask is translated into Auto Layout constraints.

```
internal func setupIntroMovie() {
        movieView = UIView(frame: view.frame)
        view.addSubview(movieView!)
        view.addSubview(logoImage)

        let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: logoImage,
                                                      attribute: .centerX,
                                                      relatedBy: .equal,
                                                      toItem: view,
                                                      attribute: .centerX,
                                                      multiplier: 1,
                                                      constant: 0)
        let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: logoImage,
                                                    attribute: .centerY,
                                                    relatedBy: .equal,
                                                    toItem: view,
                                                    attribute: .centerY,
                                                    multiplier: 1,
                                                    constant: 0)
        // Update 
        logoImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addConstraints([horizontalConstraint,
                             verticalConstraint])
        updateViewConstraints()
    }
```

> If this property’s value is true, the system creates a set of
>   constraints that duplicate the behavior specified by the view’s
>   autoresizing mask. This also lets you modify the view’s size and
>   location using the view’s  frame ,  bounds , or  center  properties,
>   allowing you to create a static, frame-based layout within Auto
>   Layout.